# How to convert not all attributes from a java object to json using jackson object mapper

Tags: java, json, jackson

I'm searching for a way to convert just a partial object (not all attrbiutes of it) via jackson to json. At the moment I'm using this solution:

```
User userServed = User.find.byId(id);
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
JsonNode node = null;
node = mapper.convertValue(userServed, JsonNode.class);
```

It works fine so far.

My Problem is that I have a lot of attributes in the Object I don't want to expose to the json node like lists. Is there a way maybe to select just the needed attributes?

Comment: What is a "partial object"?

Comment: I am referring to convert not all atributes ofthe object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you annotate the field with `JsonIgnore`?

From http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonAnnotations

> @JsonIgnore (method/field): annotation used to completely disregard
>   annotated method, regardless of auto-detection or other annotations

EDIT:  Or use the annotation `JsonIgnoreProperty`.

> (Jackson 1.4+) @JsonIgnoreProperties (class) can be used to indicate
>   that certain properties are to be ignored for serialization and/or
>   deserialization (handling differs a bit depending on which operation
>   is affected):
>
> ◦String[] value() defines logical property names to ignore (names
>   derived from getter/setter names, or by explicit annotations)
>
> ◦boolean ignoreUnknown() defines whether "unknown" JSON properties can
>   be silently ignored during deserialization or not; does not affect
>   serialization.